# ImportError: No module named config on Travis-CI build

Tags: python, configuration, flask, nose, travis-ci

I'm having an import error on [Travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/dzlab/sentimentpy), the error is related to the configuration of flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

On local machine, the flask app run correctly. But on travis here is the error trace

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=core
E.........................
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportStringError (import_string() failed for 'config'. Possible reasons are:
- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;
Debugged import:
- 'config' not found.
Original exception:
ImportError: No module named config)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/travis/build/dzlab/sentimentpy/webapp/app/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
app.config.from_object('config')
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/config.py", line 162, in from_object
obj = import_string(obj)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 426, in import_string
sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 408, in import_string
return __import__(import_name)
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'config'. Possible reasons are:
- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import_string only takes absolute module imports. Since `config` is not a top-level module, but part of `webapp`, you need to specify `webapp.config`. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('yourapplication.default_settings')
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently and could not figure it out until I had an epiphany after 2nd days by reading Markus's answer.

Just in-case someone out there is looking for a solution to load the configuration from `config.py` and the flask app is using a package structure then ensure to provide the full ***classpath*** to the config class file in `app.config.from_object()`.

For e.g., I had a configuration `myproj/app/config.py` in my flask project `myproj` and the class file with the configuration was `DevelopmentConfig`. You need to provide it as follows:

```
app.config.from_object('app.config.DevelopmentConfig')
```

Another example would be if you put the same file under `myproj/instance/config.py` then, you call it as:

```
app.config.from_object('instance.config.DevelopmentConfig')
```

During the development of your app, the easiest way to change your settings would be to put an environment variable in `myapp/.env` file like so:

```
FLASK_APP=app
APP_SETTINGS="app.config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

and use the variable in your `app.config.from_object()` call:

```
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
```

But do remember that for the .env to take effect, you need to start your app with `flask run` instead of running the app directly.